# C++, Union vs Class Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, unions

I have a certain problem and I was stuck at which approach is better than the other:

A structure with an enum that defines the data in union member OR
A group of classes with inheritance

Sample code is given below:

**Union based Structure**

```
  typedef union TokenValue{
   bool bValue;
   long lvalue;
   double dvalue;
   std::string svalue;
   }

  class Token{
  public:
   TokenType type;
   TokenValue value;
   };
```

**Class Inheritance**

```
class TokenBase{
public:
  TokenType type;
  };



class TokenNumber: public TokenBase{
public:
bool isInt;
long lvalue;
double dvalue;
};

class TokenString: public TokenBase{
 public:
  std::string svalue;
 };
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ignore some of the syntax mistakes  made while formatting the code

Comment: Unless you mention what you are going to do with this, no one can help you in a better way.

Comment: this si a piece of code from hand written lexical analyzer. Basically an object / structure that has a member that tells what data members are available based on the type. It can be done through inheritence and using union also

Comment: Your class hierarchy doesn't usable at all, because you still can't access it in polymorphic way. Consider `std::function`: it allows you to store different kinds of functions, but when you call it,  doesn't matter, what kind of function is storied. But your classes do not provide such mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of design is known as a [discriminated union or tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).  You can Google for "C++ discriminated union" to see several examples of and approaches to this type of design.

A C `union` is usually considered a bit low-level and unsafe for C++.  As [Pete Becker said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094861/25507), your `union`-based solution should provide accessors instead of directly exposing the unsafe `union` member.  `union`s also have the disadvantage that, prior to C++11, they can't contain non-POD data structures (so no `std::string`).

An inheritance-based solution has the advantage that you can start using polymorphism (e.g., add a virtual `PrintTo` method).  (You can, of course, accomplish similar results by adding a `PrintTo` method to a `union`-based solution that does a `switch` over `TokenType`, but that's non-OO.)

A `union`-based solution would probably be lighter-weight than an inheritance-based solution (no `vtable`).  That might be preferable for something as low-level as lexer tokens.

If third-party libraries are permitted, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) for a more C++ approach to discriminated unions.

Comment: I'm in the process of making a compiler. I took the union based approach (with modifications offcourse, the one here is too simplistic). I did try using inheritance based solution but it seemed like too much of an effort, and it wasn't as efficient as union based solution. I've seen some answers where people are saying don't use unions, they are bad blah blah. I want to tell them only one thing: Don't follow any rules blindly. Consider your project requirements carefully.

Comment: I just want to say this is a very nice and balanced answer. I.e. The reader is left to decide on speed vs. safety, and you have not tried to push them in either direction.

Comment: > A `union`-based solution would probably be lighter-weight than an inheritance-based solution (no `vtable`).
Aren't C++ compilers smart enough to optimize the inheritance-based solution into the `union`-based one?

Comment: @fiveseven, I'm not sure about the limits of C++ compilers' optimizations, but inheritance with a virtual function may mean "some arbitrary function may be called, _and you can't know what_" (because another implementation / subclass could always be defined in another translation unit). There are limits to how much compilers can work with that. There are plenty of discussions online about the performance impacts of vtables; see, e.g., https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/191637/3223 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-performance-benefits-of-final-classes/.

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Token` implements what's known as a "discriminated union". But its members shouldn't be public; that makes it too easy to change the type stored in the union without updating the type flag. Instead, provide overloaded accessors to store and read values. The accessor that stores a `bool` value should also set the type flag; similarly for the other accessors.

Answer (score 0):

if either/or: by default, you should favor inheritance. unions can be risky and easy to misuse. the language has good syntax and semantics regarding inheritance.

the general problem with this union is that you will have to define a good amount of implementation details which are usually abstracted from you -- construction, destruction, mode, active members…

as comments suggest -- you should detail your problem for more concrete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always, inheritance is the preferred method in C++.  The only situation I can think of a union being preferred is when data takes the same number of bits, but you don't know the proper way to interpret those bits yet.  For example, you are reading a raw stream of bits from a socket that could either be a signed or unsigned int, which you will find out from later context.  Even then, there are usually cleaner ways to implement it.